# Ansible module: should I configure using systemd or service?

Tags: ansible

I want to configure the following linux command using Ansible:

```
sudo systemctl enable XXX.service
```

should I use:

```
systemd:
  name: XXX.service
  enabled: yes
```

or

```
service:
  name: XXX.service
  enabled: yes
```

And what are the difference among using systemctl, systemd and service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to [ansible systemd module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/systemd_module.html) and [ansible service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/service_module.html) I think you should use the systemd module.

It's designed to control systemd. systemd is designed to replace service, so you can see xxx.service in systemctl command, but it's systemd system, it's different than service.

Answer (score 0):

use "service", it will systemd's systemctl command anyway.

Comment: Can you motivate your answer. IMO the accepted answer is the correct advise, your are proposing the opposite

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/service_module.html = "Controls services on remote hosts. Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart." - the "service" module is a frontend that covers the basic functionality of all. If the target system is controlled by systemd then that one is run. It says so in the documentation - and I can assure that from long years of experience with ansible automation. Even more, I have created the "docker-systemctl-replacement" system which is run by the ansible service module just fine, in the same way as systemd.

Comment: Given the choice one should use systemd. service is bound to go away eventually, one should not start something new by adding technical debt…